# SSH Remote Forwarding - Send to Background & Save Output as Variable

Tags: ssh-tunnel

I'm working on a bash script to connect to a server via SSH that is running sish (https://github.com/antoniomika/sish). This will essentially create a port forward on the internet like ngrok using only SSH. Here is what happens during normal usage.
The command:

```
ssh -i ./tun -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -R 5900:localhost:5900 tun.domain.tld sleep 10
```

The response:

```
Starting SSH Forwarding service for tcp:5900. Forwarded connections can be accessed via the following methods:
TCP: tun.domain.tld:43345
```

Now I need to send the ssh command to the background and figure out some way of capturing the response from the server as a variable so that I can grab the port that sish has assigned and send that somewhere (probably a webhook). I've tried a few things like using -f and piping to a file or named pipe and trying to cat it, but the issue is that the piping to the file never works and although the file is created, it's always empty. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you're running a single instance of sish (and the tunnel you're attempting to define) you can actually have sish bind the specific part you want (in this case 5900).

You just set the `--bind-random-ports=false` flag on your server command in order to tell sish that it's okay to not use random ports.

If you don't want to do this (or you have multiple clients that will expose this same port), you can use a simple script like the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

ADDR=""

# Start the tunnel. Use a phony command to tell ssh to clean the output.
exec 3< <(ssh -R 5900:localhost:5900 tun.domain.tld foobar 2>&1 | grep --line-buffered TCP | awk '{print $2; system("")}')

# Get our buffered output that is now just the address sish has given to us.
for i in 1; do
    read <&3 line;
    ADDR="$line"
done

# Here is where you'd call the webhook
echo "Do something with $ADDR"

# If you want the ssh command to continue to run in the background
# you can omit the following. This is to wait for the ssh command to
# exit or until this script dies in order to kill the ssh command.
PIDS=($(pgrep -P $(pgrep -P $$)))

function killssh() {
    kill ${PIDS[0]}
}

trap killssh EXIT

while kill -0 ${PIDS[0]} 2> /dev/null; do sleep 1; done;
```

sish also has an admin api which you can scrape. The information on that is available [here](https://github.com/antoniomika/sish/issues/214#issuecomment-1046159367).

References: I build and maintain [sish](https://github.com/antoniomika/sish) and use it myself (as well as a similar type of script).